# Invoke-Command for initiating Windows to update remotely is very slow, it is possible to make it run faster?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a series of script blocks I use for general PC maintenance and management.
Everything I use runs fine, until I reach to this specific point in the script, which uses the **Invoke-Command Script-Block {code here}**  Everything comes to a crawl, as it checks each PC for pending Windows updates, and then initiates said machine to update.

Script code:

```
ForEach($Session in $Sessions){
    Write-host "Checking for updates on $Session {
        $Pending = Invoke-Command -Session $Session {
        Return (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Micrososft\Windows\CurrentVersion\windowsupdate\Auto 
                Update\ Reboot Required")
        }
        if($pending ne 'True') {
            $CheckForUpdate = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
                $UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
                $Updates = $UpdatesSession.createupdatesearcher().search("IsInstalled=0 and 
                           Type='Software'").Updates
                $Updates
            } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -AsJob

            If ($Checkforupdate.count -gt 0)
            {
                $UpdatestoInstall.Add($Session.ComputerName)
                Write-Host $Session.ComputerName "has updates to install."
                }
            else
            {
                $UpdatesInstalled.Add($Session.ComputerName)
                Write-Host $Session.ComputerName "has installed all available updates"
        }
}
```

I put in **-AsJob** to see if it would make the **Invoke-Command** run any faster, and it indeed does!  Not without giving more inaccurate results, sadly.

Is there any way to make the **Invoke-Command Script-block** run more efficiently for checking, and initiating Windows updates remotely?

---

**EDIT

Here is my go at a revised version of the code:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Sessions Script-Block {
    Write-Host "Checking for updates on" $Sessions.ComputerName
    $Pending = Return (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Micrososft\Windows\CurrentVersion\windowsupdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired")

if($Pending -ne 'True') {
    $UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject "Micrsoft.Update.Session"
    $Updates = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'").Updates
    $Updates
}

if($updates.Count -qt 0) {
    $UpdatestoInstall.Add($Session.ComputerName)
    Write-Host $Session.ComputerName "has updates to install." -ForegroundColor Red
} else {
    $UpdatesInstalled.Add($Session.ComputerName)
    Write-Host $Session.ComputerName "has installed all available updates" -Foregroundcolor Green
} else {
    $UpdateReboot.Add($Session.ComputerName)
    Write-Host "A reboot is required on" $Session.ComputerName "before updates can be installed" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
Write-Host "`n"
}
```

When I run this revised script, it will only run the, **Script Block** on one machine, or I suppose the first object in the $Sessions array.

Comment: Looks like you’re running each session sequentially instead of giving all sessions to one invoke-command call.

Comment: @DougMaurer I wasn't aware you could give all sessions a single invoke-command.  Would doing this still be able to get specific results for each remote machine?
*EDIT: I just read that I could hypothetically use **Invoke-command -Session $Sessions -ScriptBlock {#code here} -asJob**  Would this be viable?

Comment: No need to do it as job. And I’d say -erroraction SilentlyContinue and -errorvariable errors that way it won’t stop on failure and when it’s complete you can inspect $errors for those that didn’t work

Comment: I have been working on a solution to a similar problem in this post that may be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317890/how-can-i-create-jobs-that-yield-results-as-they-complete

Comment: @DougMaurer I have tried some testing, but I had had no luck with trying to get it to work under a single script block.

Comment: Please explain if this is your real code, or if you added newlines and spaces at places they shouldn't be in an attempt to format it for SO? `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Micrososft\Windows\CurrentVersion\windowsupdate\Auto Update\ Reboot Required` should be `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired`.

Comment: Also `if($pending ne 'True')`.. the operator needs a dash `-ne`, but since the scriptblock returns a boolean value, just do `if(!$pending)`

Comment: @Theo I had to rewrite my code, so it's not an exact copy and paste from the actual script to the chunk here on SO.  The `if(!$Pending)` is good to know, though!

Comment: Can you please paste a revised version if the code?

Comment: @alexzelaya I updated the post with an edit, and the revised code I came up with.

Comment: You spelled microsoft wrong in the first registry key.

Comment: Also, you can't have a double `else` condition.

Comment: Change to `if(!$pending) {` and finally `if($updates.Count -gt 0) {`